# Move multiple elements within a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got the following code repeated for 8 different menu items:

```
<li>
<a> <img class="menu-img" src="bg.jpg"></a>
<div class="sub-container">
<div class="sub-menu"></div>
 </div>

</li>
```

Now I want to move the img down into the sub-container which i've managed to achieve with the following code:

```
  $("img.menu-img") //element i'm targetting
    .appendTo(".sub-container"); // where I'm moving it to
```

But as you've guessed it everytime I add another image to a different menu it's adding it to this container. How do I make it so it only moves the image down into the child of that element so each menu will have an unique image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate all matches then navigate a branch to find the target for each img:

```
$("img.menu-img").each(function(){

    // Find the closest parent LI element
    var li = $(this).closest('li');

    // Find the container within that LI and move the image (this) under there
    li.find(".sub-container").append(this);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/95wtuuw9/

Comment: You sir are a saint. Thanks!

Comment: Always best to do local navigation, so that your code survives most DOM changes to the page. Glad it helped :)